# sign up not working for heroku hosted scoold

Tags: heroku, scoold

Hi I deployed scoold to heroku following the steps [here](https://github.com/Erudika/scoold/blob/master/README.md). The application is running but I cannot sign in to an account. When I tried to sign up for an account it shows that a confirmation email is sent but I don't receive one. Anyone know what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have not configured SMTP properly. You need a real SMTP server with a username and password. After configuring it you can resend your email confirmation and log in.

You can enable SMTP debug logging with this option:

```
para.mail.debug = true
```